# How to enable both "diag" and "rndis" port of Android?

Tags: root-access, rom, kernel, magisk, diagnostics

I have One Plus Nord device which is rooted using Magisk. I am able to enable the usb tethering(rndis) and capturing modem logs(diag) separately using the libusb program. But the requirement is to capture the diag logs when the phone is connected with laptop and usb tethering is enabled. Following are the commands used to enable the ports:

1. To enable "Usb Tethering"

`adb shell su -c "setprop sys.usb.config rndis,none,adb"`

2. To enable the "Diag"

`adb shell su -c "setprop sys.usb.config diag,adb"`

I have tried to enable both using different set of commands like

- `adb shell su -c "setprop sys.usb.config rndis,diag,adb"`
- `adb shell su -c "setprop sys.usb.config rndis,none,diag,adb"`
- `adb shell su -c "setprop sys.usb.config diag,rndis,adb"`

etc.. bot none is working.

Does anyone have knowledge of how to use both together or any hint which can help in achieving the goal?

Comment: have you tried magisk resetprop to set properties on boot (not runtime)?